# VLC doesn't start, says bus error (core dumped)

Tags: vlc

This is what happens:

```
~ $ vlc
VLC media player 2.2.0-pre2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.0-pre1-15-g5178b24)
[00000000017db118] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Tried removing vlc config files from the home dir as was suggested by some other threads, didn't help. Also tried reporting a bug directly to their bug tracker, but it's not working, can't even login there.

Ideas?

Comment: can you also specify your distro specs.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10, 64 bit

Comment: do you have any ppas enabled e.g. `ppa:videolan/stable-daily` ?

Comment: ~$ vlc
VLC media player 2.1.4 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4-0-g2a072be)
[0x1251118] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Bus error (core dumped)

Same error. I got an Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 64 bit on a Dell Inspiron N5110

Comment: I tried: vlc --reset-config  ; sudo apt-get remove vlc browser-plugin-vlc ; sudo apt-get autoremove ; sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc ;  Same error and VLC doesn't Loads. :(

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish I don't have that ppa in my /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: try to add this ppa with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily` then update `apt` and reinstall vlc with `install --reinstall` command and reply if it changes anything.

Comment: I added the ppa, reinstalled VLC as you suggested. Getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a bug: https://wiki.videolan.org/Report_bugs/
After updating to latest version maybe trying to run:

```
gdb /usr/bin/vlc
```

then "r" and enter
then cause VLC to crash
then "bt" and enter
and copy all the output including the output of "`vlc -vvv`" (to the point it crashed) + OS version to VLC (see the link above)